# Cayley Table Wikipedia Notation

Tags: group-theory, notation, finite-groups, cayley-table

Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_(group_theory)) that this is a Cayley table of Dih4:

[image: Cayley table of Dih4 group]

Can somebody explain what are these numbers/colors mean?
[Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_table) on Cayley table uses letters and does not mention any numbers.

Also what are these small tables with red squares on top/left mean?
There are other examples of such a schemes like [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group_of_order_6)

**Update:**

I recently figured out that 'small tables with red squares' are actually a [permutation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix) corresponding to the group's elements, but the question about numbers and colors is still open.

**Update 2:**

as Nex pointed out the numbers come from Caley table of S4 group. [Symmetric group S4 page](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Symmetric_group_S4) contains explanation of the colors:

Even permutations are white:

- the identity
- eight 3-cycles
- three double-transpositions (in bold typeface)
  Odd permutations are colored:
- six transpositions (green)
- six 4-cycles (orange)

Comment: That has got to be one of the most confusing diagrams I've ever seen, of Cayley tables or otherwise.

Comment: the black dot is probably the identity

Comment: Do the numbers make any sense in binary? I do agree that this is, at best, confusing. I know wiki articles can be somewhat hard to learn from, as they are a reference, but this is quite unhelpful.

Comment: I think the numbers come from seeing this group as a subgroup of https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Watchduck#/media/File:Symmetric_group_4;_Cayley_table;_numbers.svg